# Corrupted WAV audio files in iOS - why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, audio, avfoundation

I'm recording WAV files and sending them to a server, but the server doesn't seem to recognize and manipulate the WAV files recorded on the device - any other WAV file works. I wonder if I've done something wrong with any setting of `AVAudioRecorder`.

```
let settings: [String:AnyObject] = [
     AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
     AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
     AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
     AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
     AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: true
]
```

This is the function that records audio coming from the microphone:

```
var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
var audioURL = NSURL()

func startRecording() {
    recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        // failed to record!
    }

    let audioFilename = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    audioURL = audioFilename.URLByAppendingPathComponent("recording.wav")

     let settings: [String:AnyObject] = [
          AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
          AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
          AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
          AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
          AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: true
     ]

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()
        audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        print("Recording...")
    } catch {
          // error
    }
}

// I'm done! Send file to server
func uploadFileAudioToServer() {
    let path = "recordings/" + "userNameGoesHere" + ".wav"
    amazonS3Manager.putObject(audioURL, destinationPath: path).responseS3Data({ (response) -> Void in
        print("File uploaded")
    })
}
```

What could be wrong in this method?

Comment: Please take a look at the order of statements where you start the recording. It looks to me like they might be in an incorrect order. I would also suggest that you to take an audio file processing application, perhaps on your Mac, and examine the parameters of both a successful file and of one you have recorded to see where they differ

Comment: Are you calling `audioRecorder.stop()` before you upload? p.s. I think your `AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey` flag is being ignored.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm able to play the .wav file but whenever I try to convert it's Base64Encoded string, the data seems to be corrupted.

Comment: So any workaround for that @Cesare ?

Comment: I've figured it out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376645/8164116