# Can't encode an Audio file to Base64?

Tags: ios, wav, swift4.2, voice-recording

**Objective: Dialog Flow Voice Bot Api**

I need to send a wav file to the Dialog Flow Api and the format and settings were pre-defined.

- So I recorded an audio using `AVAudioRecorder` in `.wav` format using
  following settings

```
audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("input.wav")

let settings: [String: Any] = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
    AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue
]

do {
    audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename!, settings: settings)
    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.record()
    recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Stop", for: .normal)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    finishRecording(success: false)
    }
}
```

- Then I tried to convert it into `Base64` audio format

```
let outputFile = try Data.init(contentsOf: fileUrl)
let base64String = outputFile.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
print(base64String)
```

So whenever I try to decode that encoded string, using an [online converter](https://www.base64decode.org), it displays some corrupted bytes 
[image: Decoded output]

Thoughts??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've found the answer to the question.
The reason my byte array wasn't able to maintain correct headers was because of the following key that I omitted in the `settings` variable

```
AVAudioFileTypeKey: kAudioFileWAVEType
```

```
    let settings: [String: Any] = [
      AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
      AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
      AVAudioFileTypeKey: kAudioFileWAVEType,  //MANDATORY
      AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
      AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
      AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: true,
      AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]
```

It was given in the **docs** that if you won't provide the settings i.e.

`audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename!, settings: [:] /*empty settings*/)`

then

> ❌ AVAudio recorder will automatically prepare the file from the **Format** defined in the file. ❌

But turns out, that **didn't help either**

So whilst I was playing with the settings, I found this **very important** key `AVAudioFileTypeKey`, which helped in maintaining the correct headers and thus a valid `.wav` file

This is how a wav file with Valid headers look like
[image: A valid file]